# awk Replace second field with millisecond from first field

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Given the text below:

```
2014-01-21 15:59:18.916,2014-01-21 15:59:19.232
2014-01-21 16:02:25.917,2014-01-21 16:02:28.457
```

I'm looking for an awk statement that changes it to:

```
2014-01-21 15:59:18.916,916
2014-01-21 16:02:25.917,917
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash:

```
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2; do
    echo "$f1,${f1##*.}"
done << END
2014-01-21 15:59:18.916,2014-01-21 15:59:19.232
2014-01-21 16:02:25.917,2014-01-21 16:02:28.457
END
```

```
2014-01-21 15:59:18.916,916
2014-01-21 16:02:25.917,917
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just remove 2nd value after the comma and add the millisecond of the first field, then this should suffice:

```
$ awk -F"[.,]" '{print $1"."$2","$2}' file
2014-01-21 15:59:18.916,916
2014-01-21 16:02:25.917,917
```

What it does is to define two possible field separators with `-F"[.,]"` and then print 1st, 2nd and 2nd fields based on that separation.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/\.\([0-9]*\),.*/.\1,\1/' file
```